# Correct syntax to define an IQueryable<TSource>.OrderBy( ) like method

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6, extension-methods

I need to create an extension method for a checking I need to do  for database table queries. That checking is the same I need to do in all controllers in an MVC application, for different tables in the model. That is why I want to centralize the code in an extension method.

For you to understand the context, I will explain using an invented and simplified case.

Suppose I have two Db entities called `ATable` and `BTable`. Both have a relation to `Company` table.

In normal circumstances I use this code to filter by a company condition:

```
var queryA = db.ATable.where(a => a.Company.IsEnabled)

var queryB = db.BTable.where(b => b.Company.IsEnabled)
```

Condition is more complex than that but with this simplified case it will be clear.

My idea is to call something like:

```
var queryA = db.ATable.CheckByCompany(a => a.Company);

var queryB = db.BTable.CheckByCompany(b => b.Company);
```

That is, to call the method only with the related property and that method will be responsible to create the whole condition on that property. That way of calling resembles the `OrderBy` extension method, so I think I could do something similar.

My first attempt was to create an interface called `ICompany` with `Company` as the only property and to implement it in `ATable` and `BTable` classes. That way I created this method:

```
    public static IQueryable<TSource> CheckByCompany<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
          where T: ICompany
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        IQueryable<TSource> query = source.Where(t => source.Company.IsEnabled);

        // The rest of the conditions I need for Company entity.

        return query;
    }
```

That compiles at least, but an exception is thrown at runtime because ICompany is not recognized by Linq.

My next attempt could be to create a method similar to OrderBy extension method, but I am lost about the correct syntax to define it.

I did something like:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> CheckByCompany<TSource, Company>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, Company>> company)
```

But, after that, how can I use it? Is that method signature correct?

I saw the source code for OrderBy extension method but it is not really easy to follow.

Any advice, please?

Jaime

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want your `CheckByCompany` to do. If I pass in `a => a.Company`, it will turn into a `Where(a => a.Company.IsEnabled)` call. What other lambda expressions can I pass in there?

Comment: Condition is very more complex than that. It is also constructed dynamically depending on some variables present in the web page. All tables in the model are related to Company entity and that condition is called several times, in each controller of the MVC application. If, for some reason, that condition is changed, I will need to change it several times with the possibilty to do a mistake. If that is the case, it will be easier just to modify the condition in one place.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question?... It sounds like you won't be passing anything else other than `a => a.Company` in there... Then why have a parameter at all?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I will only pass `a.Company` to the extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have implemented the solution like the mentioned in this page: https://codingsight.com/using-expressions-to-filter-data-of-database/

My final extension method is this:

```
    public static IQueryable<TSource> FiltraEmpresaCliente<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, ParentController controller, Expression<Func<TSource, Empresa>> empresa)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        if (empresa == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> filterValidity = entity => empresa.Call()(entity).Cliente.ClienteEliminadoEn == null && empresa.Call()(entity).Cliente.ClienteVigente && empresa.Call()(entity).EmpresaEliminadoEn == null && empresa.Call()(entity).EmpresaVigente;
        Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> filterCustomer = null;
        Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> filterCompany = null;

        var empresaId = controller.EmpresaID;
        if (empresaId > 0)
            filterCompany = entity => empresa.Call()(entity).EmpresaId == empresaId;

        var clienteId = controller.ClienteID;
        if (clienteId > 0)
            filterCustomer = entity => empresa.Call()(entity).ClienteId == clienteId;

        IQueryable<TSource> query = source.Where(filterValidity.SubstituteMarker());

        if (filterCompany != null)
            query = query.Where(filterCompany.SubstituteMarker());

        if (filterCustomer != null)
            query = query.Where(filterCustomer.SubstituteMarker());

        return query;
    }
```

It works, however, I am wondering what about performance. Have you got some comments?

Regards
Jaime